# jCarousellite pauseonhover and mousewheel together not working

Tags: jquery, jcarousellite

I m using jCarousellite to scroll slider. But mousewheel scroll does not work when I put `pauseonHover:true`. Any suggestion?

```
$('.slider').jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: ".next",
    btnPrev: ".prev",
    vertical: true,
    auto: true,
    timeout: 2800,
    speed: 400,
    easing: 'easeOutQuint',
    pauseOnHover: true,
    start: randNum,
    mouseWheel: true
});
```

Comment: Make sure you are not hovering over the the slider when you attempt to scroll with the wheel?

Comment: @Dom-TaphillStudios. Yes I already have checked that. Its not working even if my cursor is out of slider.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [jCarousel Lite documentation](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/documentation.php) pauseOnHover is not a valid option.

I would recommend using [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/) there's much better documentation and more support through its popularity.